# Ansible: want to apply variables to a group of inventories

Tags: ansible

I have some inventories defined, containing software version numbers defined in variables.

I'd like to share the same version numbers between my prod and UAT inventories in order to guarantee that a prod release matches what was tested in UAT.

Is is possible to share variables between some inventories and not others (I suppose this might mean conceptually "grouping" inventories)?

Example of my current setup

Content of `/prod/group_vars/all`:

> ```
>    my-app-verion: 1.0.0
> ```

Content of `/uat/group_vars/all`:

> ```
>    my-app-verion: 1.0.0
> ```

Content of `/dev/group_vars/all`:

> ```
>    my-app-verion: LATEST
> ```

I would like to have one file that's shared by the `prod` and `uat` inventories and contains

> ```
>     my-app-verion: 1.0.0
> ```

Comment: Could you add an example of your variables/inventory files? It can get quite problematic setting many variables in inventory.

Comment: @RamondelaFuente I have updated the question with more detail

Comment: Ok.. I don't quite see the reason so have subdirectories there. If you use the grouping in your inventory file the group_vars would solve the problem (basic inventory http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html) with a group that has prod and uat as children. But I might not have a full picture of your setup yet..

Comment: @RamondelaFuente - unfortunately I define "clusters" within an inventory (there are two clusters for prod and two for uat). So things are going to get messy if I put all of my environments and all their constituent clusters into one big file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use groups in inventories? There can be a release group and a latest group. Then you can have group_vars/release and group_vars/latest

Your inventory files would be:

prod:

```
[release]
prod1
prod2
```

prodlike:

```
[release]
prod3
prod4
```

test:

```
[latest]
dev1
dev2
```

mixedenv:

```
[releasse]
lab1
lab2
[latest]
lab3
```

Comment: You can also use [child groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#id9) so in the dev inventory `[latest:children] all` or `[latest:children] devhosts` if the hosts are in a group called `devhosts`

Answer (score 0):

You can group inventory files together by making inventory directories. Put multiple inventory files in one directory. You can then target the inventory directory when you run a playbook and Ansible will load inventory from all files in the directory.

You can also put your group_vars and host_vars directories in this directory.

Comment: I am able to put multiple inventory files (prod, uat etc) in one directory containing a `group_vars/all` directory with my shared variables. However, I'm then unable to add variables that are specific to prod, or uat (such variables used to live in the `prod/group_vars/all` or `uat/group_vars/all` directories)